# Android notifications at unknown times

Tags: android, google-play, android-notifications

I would like the users of my app to receive notifications in the OS's notification drawer, with a message and icon, and when the notification is pressed, my app will open. I don't know exactly when I want to send the notifications, just sometime in the future after I publish it...is this possible to do?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: I'll try to clarify: I want to publish my app tomorrow on the Google-play market. And every month or so, I want to send notifications to everyone that has my app installed on their device, so they will see it along with all their other notifications (like SMS, email, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This that you think to do it's possible, but you should to implement a Server. In the next link show how do this with a PHP server and how implement the GCM. http://androidexample.com/Android_Push_Notifications_using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=119&aaid=139

To do this you can send in body of the request a JSON object, like this:

```
{
    message: 'my own GCM request',
    description: 'description',
    type: 1
}
```

And others parameters you need

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that's not exactly what I was looking for. After the user installed my app, I want to be able to send a notification to him/her without them having to sign up for anything. Just a simple message like "New content now available"

Comment: I guess it's not possible, and this is the best solution available; so I'll mark it as the correct answer. Thanks.